# Can't run IDLE with pyenv installation: `Python may not be configured for Tk` `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named _tkinter'

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, python-idle, pyenv

I recently spent couple hours making `tkinter` and IDLE work on my `pyenv` Python installation (macOS).

**Why you are here?**

1. You manage Python versions with `pyenv` on macOS **and**
2. **(** You want IDLE - the development environment for Python - work on your macOS
3. or you want `tkinter` module work **)**

**What's wrong?**

You get one of the following errors:

1. `Python may not be configured for Tk` on `import tkinter`
2. `import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk`
3. `RuntimeError: tk.h version (8.6) doesn't match libtk.a version (8.5)`
4. `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is **step by step guide** to make IDLE and `tkinter` work:

1. install `tcl-tk` with Homebrew. In shell run `brew install tcl-tk`
2. in shell run `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`
3. reload shell by quitting `Terminal` app or run `source ~/.zshrc`
4. after reloaded check that `tck-tk` is in `$PATH`. Run `echo $PATH | grep --color=auto tcl-tk`. As the result you should see your $PATH contents with `tcl-tk` highlighted
5. now we run three commands from Homebrew's output from step #1

   1. in shell run `export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib"`
   2. in shell run `export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/include"`
   3. in shell run `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib/pkgconfig"`
6. if you have your Python version already installed with `pyenv` then uninstall it with `pyenv uninstall <your python version>`. E.g. `pyenv uninstall 3.8.2`
7. set environment variable that will be used by `python-build`. In shell run `export PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-tcltk-includes='-I/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/include' --with-tcltk-libs='-L/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib -ltcl8.6 -ltk8.6'"`
   *Note: in future use `tck-tk` version that actually installed with Homebrew. At the moment of posting `8.6` was the actual*
8. finally install Python with `pyenv` with `pyenv install <version>`. E.g. `pyenv install 3.8.2`

**Test**

1. in shell run `pyenv global <verion that you've just installed>`
2. now check IDLE. In shell run `idle`. You should see IDLE window without any warnings and "text printed in red".

[image: IDLE window run from Terminal. No warnings]

3. now check `tkinter`. In shell run `python -m tkinter -c "tkinter._test()"`. You should see test window like on the image:

[image: tkinter test window]

That's it!

**My environment:**

check this is something went wrong executing steps above:

1. macOS Catalina
2. `zsh` (included in macOS Catalina) = **"shell" above**
3. Homebrew (installed with instructions from Homebrew official website)
4. `pyenv` (installed with Homebrew and PATH updated according to `pyenv` official readme from GitHub)
5. Python `3.8.x` - `3.9.x` (installed with `pyenv install <version>` command)

Comment: In step 7 above, setting the environment variable PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS should start with export keyword, no?  Otherwise, this worked great for me.

Comment: Both of you have saves my life. I tried other approaches and they didn't work. @PapaJoeDee was right, I needed to add export to step 7 in order for it to work.

Comment: My environment are: Big Sur 11.3.1, Xcode 12.5, Python 3.8.2
Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.4.0
----

This saved my day man! Thanks so much [nickolay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/823048/nickolay). Also, don't skip any step, any step here is necessary to get the tk work.

Comment: This worked! My `tk-tl` was flickering and not displaying anything when I tried using Turtle beforehand. Sure enough, despite being on python 3.10.2 through pyenv, it was still using `tk-tl` 8.5.9. Followed these steps and it was fixed. Note: for Apple M1 chips, the path is `/opt/homebrew`, not `/opt/local`

Comment: Thank you. I need this and this worked for me with pyenv 2.2.5 on macOS 12.3.1 and on arm (Apple M1). Note that home-brew installs in /opt/homebrew on Macs running Apple Silicon, so setting the PATH was different in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why the above didn't work for me. What did work after hours of headache was:

```
$ brew install python-tk
```

Comment: `Homebrew` does the job if you're going to use only one `python` version on your OS. For multiple `python` versions e.g. managed with `pyenv` you'll have to go beyond `Homebrew`