# I can't find IDLE after I install Python with Homebrew

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, python-idle

I've recently moved myself over to macOS so apologies if this is a very silly question, but I've installed Python 3 using `brew install python`, and although it's available to use as expected via a CLI, I can't for the life of me find IDLE anywhere on my system, and can't launch it using anything like Spotlight.

Have I missed something when installing?

Thanks!

Comment: Try ```idle-python``` in the terminal

Comment: `zsh: command not found: idle-python` I'm afraid 

Comment: I don't know for MacOS but for Ubuntu, for idle, it's ```sudo apt install idle-python3.8```

Comment: I've tried `brew install idle-python` which would be the closest approximation I can think of to no avail.

Comment: Simply type idle

Comment: So that worked in terminal, but it's not ideal to have to launch this way every time. I'm wondering if there's a way to add it to my Applications folder somehow, which is what happens when Python is installed via the python.org installer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792044/how-do-i-launch-idle-the-development-environment-for-python-on-mac-os-10-7 check

Answer (score 11):

On my machine (macOS Monterey version 12.3.1) IDLE is symlinked at `/usr/local/bin/idle3` i.e. I can run it using `idle3` (note the `3`, not just `idle`)

```bash
idle3
```

I had to also install `Tkinter` using `brew install python-tk` because on first run IDLE complained it couldn't import Tkinter

```plaintext
** IDLE can't import Tkinter.
Your Python may not be configured for Tk. **
```

```bash
brew install python-tk
```

After that IDLE worked as expected and a Python shell window is opened.

Thanks to the [Installing Python 3 on MacOS](https://www.devdungeon.com/content/installing-python-3-macos) DevDungeon page for pointing me at `idle3` and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459444/tkinter-python-may-not-be-configured-for-tk#answer-67465708) answer to the [Tkinter: "Python may not be configured for Tk"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459444/tkinter-python-may-not-be-configured-for-tk) question on Stack Overflow.