# How to change MySQL Connector installation directory?

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to Install MySQL Connector using "pip install mysql-connector-python" but it says that

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): mysql-connector-python in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

I am using Python IDLE and i want to somehow install mysql-connector in IDLE`s modules directory and so MySQLdb.

How do i change the default directory which is /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages to the one used by IDLE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You best use virtualenv, and [make IDLE work in a virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924068/how-to-launch-python-idle-from-a-virtual-environment-virtualenv). This way you can just install Connector/Python as usual.

Or you can install MySQL Connector/Python in a different folder and add it to the PYTHONPATH when launching IDLE:

```
shell> pip install --target=/tmp/myconnpy --allow-external mysql-connector-python mysql-connector-python
shell> PYTHONPATH="/tmp/myconnpy" idle
```

pip 1.4.1 has apparently problems using --target when the package is already installed system-wide, even using --ignore-installed. So you'll need to remove the package first first.