# How to launch idlex from virtualenv through python script

Tags: python

I am trying to automate a couple of steps I have to do repeatedly on windows, like open command prompt and starting virtualenv and then launching idlex. I am writing a python script which I can double click to automatically perform both these steps. I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924068/how-to-launch-python-idle-from-a-virtual-environment-virtualenv) but couldn't understand it. Below is the script I have written where I am making two calls to Popen

```
import subprocess

#launches virtualenv in command prompt
proc1 = subprocess.Popen('start\
                        "IDLE"\
                        /d c:\\Python27\\fp\
                        /wait\
                        C:\\Python27\\fp\\Scripts\\activate.bat',
                        shell=True,
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
#starts idlex
proc2 = subprocess.Popen('start\
                        "IDLE"\
                        /B\
                        /d c:\\Python27\\fp\
                        /wait\
                        c:\\Python27\\fp\\scripts\\python.exe\
                        C:\\Python27\\fp\\Scripts\\idlex.py',
                        shell=True,
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I want to perform both these steps without making second Popen call, but communicate() isn't working and I don't understand why. Is it because `start` spawns another process whose handle isn't available?