# HOW to install oauth in python

Tags: python-2.7, oauth-2.0

I tried to install oauth in python 2 using the 'pip install' command in command prompt but it get installed in the anaconda software.I want to use in python 2.Can anyone please tell me how to install it so that I can use it in python 2

Comment: Have you considered using a `virtualenv` to make it explicit which Python interpreter and packages should be used for a given project?

Comment: i looked at it but I won't be able to use oauth in my python 2 idle with this.Is there a way I can install pip such that it is installed in my python 2 libraries?

Comment: *"I won't be able to use oauth in my python 2 ide"* - what? Why not? What IDE are you using?

Comment: I use python 2.7 idle.I also installed virtualenv.Now what should I do to use oauth in python 2.7?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4924068/3001761 - note that some more mature editors like PyCharm handle virtual environments natively.

Comment: I read on another stackoverflow query that I can also install it manually.Can anyone please tell me where in c:\python 27 should I keep 'python-oauth2-0.7.0' folder?This folder contains setup.py file for oauth2

Comment: should I keep it in scripts folder?

Comment: If you've `pip install`ed it you don't need the `setup.py`

Comment: I did pip install but oauth got installed only in anaconda 2,not in python 2.7.Isn't there any way it can be done in python 2.7 as well?

Comment: ...I feel like we're going around in circles. Once you've activated the virtualenv you can pip install it there.