# Making Python IDLE use virtualenv by default

Tags: python, cmd, pip, virtualenv

I installed Python 3.6 on my windows in the standard manner (IDLE being located at `..Python36-32\Lib`)

What I want is for IDLE to default to my virtualenv. Is there a way I can do it?

I searched and found this post but the last reply in the post makes me believe that most of the answers there are for Python version 2.7
[How to launch python Idle from a virtual environment (virtualenv)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924068/how-to-launch-python-idle-from-a-virtual-environment-virtualenv/10367004#10367004)

Comment: Sorry maybe I should have added. Yes I did go and activate virtualenv via CMD, but I believe that just like in the other post, the issue is more to do with IDLE deciding to pick the default as the "non-virtualenv"

Comment: What do you mean by "default"?

Comment: What I meant by "default" was...like when I try to run any python file (even if I just double-click the file), windows should only run it via the virtualenv and never ever go to my standard "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32" folder. If that makes sense? So basically, I am looking for the "isolation" advantage of virtualenv without having to open the CMD window.