# Why module installed in virtual environment is available in bash and not in idle?

Tags: algorithm, module, python-3.8

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
System wide python version is 2.7.17 (obviously), I also have number of virtual environments set up. Today happened something that I don't yet understand, namely:

- I activated my (3.8) environment
- Then downloaded a module:

  ```
  (3.8) $ pip install algorithms
  ```
- Started up idle-python3.8:

  ```
  (3.8) $ idle-python3.8 &
  ```
- Attempted to import my freshly downloaded module:

  ```
  >>> import algorithms
  ```
- Then, I saw this error popping up:

  ```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
      import algorithms
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'algorithms'
  ```
- I closed idle and made sure the module is installed:

  ```
  (3.8) $ pip list
  Package                Version
  ---------------------- -------
  algorithms             0.1.4
  astroid                2.4.2
  autopep8               1.5.4
  backcall               0.2.0
  decorator              4.4.2
  ......
  .....
  ```
- I had to make sure...:

  ```
  (3.8) $ python --version
  Python 3.8.0
  ```
- Then I tried this:

  ```
  (3.8) $ python3.8
  Python 3.8.0 (default, Oct 28 2019, 16:14:01) 
  [GCC 8.3.0] on linux
  Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
  >>> import algorithms
  >>>
  ```

What?! How?! Can someone enlighten me please? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idle runs in global environment. You have to start it like  this:

```
python -m idlelib.idle
```

See detailed answer here:
[How to launch python Idle from a virtual environment (virtualenv)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924068/how-to-launch-python-idle-from-a-virtual-environment-virtualenv)