# Why a module present in pipfile gives unresolved reference when tried to import

Tags: python, pipenv

i was working in a virtual environment in python

in my pipfile under

[packages]

is present `imap-tools = "==0.24.0"`

but when i try to `import imap_tools`

IDLE (pycharm) gives 'unresolved Reference'

also
when i tried to install imap_tools inside virtual environment

pip3 install imap-tools==0.24.0

but it shows requirement already satisfied

and again same error of unresolved reference while importing imap_tools

Comment: How did you start your IDLE? (Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924068/how-to-launch-python-idle-from-a-virtual-environment-virtualenv)

Answer (score 0):

You must activate the venv before installing, otherwise it would try to install in the external site packages:

```
source venv_name/bin/activate 
pip install imap-tools
```